# Поиск подстроки в строке android. Выкидывается exception

Tags: java, android

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            Address="http://"+editText.getText().toString();
            WebSettings webSettings=web.getSettings();
            web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            web.loadUrl(Address);
        }
```

Создаю обычный браузер. Все работает как надо и так далее. Но захотел добавить проверку на присутствие http в ссылке. Использую стандартную функцию contains.

```
If(Address.contains("http://"){//Тут у меня неважно какой код.}
```

Если я делаю подобное, то у меня вылетает exception:

> 11-09 14:41:41.760 30621-30621/com.example.karas.thirdattempt
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                       Process: com.example.karas.thirdattempt, PID: 30621
>                                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                           at
>   com.example.karas.thirdattempt.BrowserETC.checkForWord(BrowserETC.java:41)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.example.karas.thirdattempt.BrowserETC.onClick(BrowserETC.java:32)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: Покажите весь код. Очевидно, что у вас там `Address` равен `null`.

Comment: Да, я нашел ошибку. Спасибо

Comment: If(Address.contains("http://") видимо скобки не хватало

Comment: Я там сам вызывал exception, по невнимательности